# Angular2-google-maps library cant be installed

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to install the library angular2-google-maps but it keeps throwing me erros when I try to. Here is the library I want to use: https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html

It keeps throwing me this errord!

[image]

Can somebody help me out on this!? This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "primeng": "^0.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-bless": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings": "^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

As you can see I all ready got version rxjs: 5.0.0-beta.2

[image]

Now suddenly it is not in registry of npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try doing this:

in your `package.json` file under `dependecies` add `"angular2-google-maps":"0.10.0"` then in the project folder do `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Your Node.JS version 0.10.25 is too old. Please update to v5 or higher